# TensorFlow Serving Error - Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to restore a TensorFlow's Saver object (.ckpt.*) and convert it into SavedModel object(.pb) so that I can deploy it with TensorFlow Serving.

This is how I convert:

```py
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        # Restore the graph from (.meta .data .index)
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(f"{checkpoint_path}/{meta_file_string}")
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(str(checkpoint_path)))


        # Convert into ".pb" using SavedModel API.
        model_path = f'{savedmodel_path}/1'
        builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(model_path)

        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess, [tf.saved_model.SERVING],
            main_op=tf.tables_initializer(),
            strip_default_attrs=True)

        builder.save()
        print("Saved")
```

Saving seems to work fine when I tree:

```sh
$ tree 1
1
├── saved_model.pb
└── variables
    ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
    └── variables.index

1 directory, 3 files
```

and when I use saved_model_cli:

```sh
$ saved_model_cli show --dir path/to/model/1
The given SavedModel contains the following tag-sets:
serve
```

However, when I run the TensorFlow serving docker container,

```sh
$ docker run \
-p 8500:8500 \
-v path/to/model:/models/aaa \
--env MODEL_NAME=aaa \
--name aaa \
tensorflow/serving
```

it complains that it cannot find the tag "serve" which I DID ADD:

```
2019-11-19 02:35:30.844163: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /models/aaa/1
2019-11-19 02:35:30.916952: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2019-11-19 02:35:30.927640: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:311] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: fail. Took 83527 microseconds.
2019-11-19 02:35:30.927781: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] Loading servable: {name: aaa version: 1} failed: Not found: Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`
```

What have I done wrong, how can I fix this?
otherwise, how can I dive into this issue deeper?

I am using **tensorflow 1.14.0**.
and using docker image **tensorFlow-serving:1.14.0-devel**.

Comment: `saved_model_cli show --dir ./your/saved/model --all` use this to see meta graph also paste output here

Comment: ```saved_model_cli show --dir 1 --all``` returns:


```MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:``` (nothing after the 'SignatureDefs:')

Comment: I think you need to add prediction signature to your meta graph and then check with saved_model_cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `tensorflow/serving` image with `:latest` version, which is `:2.0.0` so far. And worked fine.

My local train environment still uses TensorFlow 1.14
No idea why this is so.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add prediction signature to your builder-

```
prediction_signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def({"input": inputs}, {"output":output})

builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder('exported_moddel/')

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(session,
                                     [tag_constants.SERVING],
                                    signature_def_map={"classification":prediction_signature})
builder.save()
```

you can refer this notebook for more detail - https://github.com/CS-savvy/tf-graph-preprocessing-addition/blob/master/keras%20inject.ipynb

Comment: I omitted :1.14.0-dev during troubleshooting and used latest version (by mistake), and somehow, solved the issue.

Your reference was still useful anyway. vote up!!
thanks for your help :)

Comment: where I get inputs and outputs value for '.predict_signature_def({"input": inputs}, {"output":output})'?

Comment: @B.Kanani inputs and output should be tensors which go in the model and the one comes out from the model. you can check the above-mentioned notebook for full implimentation

Comment: Although, I am not sure whether codes are compatible with tf2 or not.